# Huge Compression Difference in RAR archive and Gzip: Is there anything that I am missing?

Tags: python, compression, gzip, archive, winrar

I have a huge text file of about **500MB** in size. I tried to archive it with **Gzip** both from a python program and the command line. But, in both cases the archived file's size is about **240MB**, whereas while archiving with **WinRAR** in Windows, the archived file size is around **450KB**. Is there something I am missing here? Why is there so much difference and what can I do to achieve the similar level of compression?

I have tagged this with Python also, as any python code regarding this will be very helpful.

Here is first 3 lines of the [file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4Rf_mQEJerQVUxEVndvdHhGNlk):

```
$ head 100.txt -n 3
31731610:22783120;
22783120:
45476057:39683372;5879272;54702019;58780534;30705698;60087296;98422023;55173626;5607459;843581;11846946;97676518;46819398;60044103;48496022;35228829;6594795;43867901;66416757;81235384;42557439;40435884;60586505;65993069;76377254;82877796;94397118;39141041;2725176;56097923;4290013;26546278;18501064;27470542;60289066;43986553;67745714;16358528;63833235;92738288;77291467;54053846;93392935;10376621;15432256;96550938;25648200;10411060;3053129;54530514;97316324;
```

Comment: It totally depends on which algorithms are used and what data is in the file.

Comment: Different algorithms, different butter zones.  Obviously, you hit the one of WinRAR.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, I know that, the text file mostly consists of numbers and ':'s. I just want to know if it is possible to achieve the same level of archiving as the output size from WinRAR and Gzip are very contrasting.

Comment: Can we see the file? Throw the .rar in a public dropbox or something - I'm curious. I wonder if gzip doesn't handle random text very well, it does pattern matching with backreferences, but maybe your file is unique in that there aren't many references to be made.

Comment: @Tass:I have added a few lines from my file. If you wish you can download the file from here:[link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4Rf_mQEJerQVUxEVndvdHhGNlk)

Comment: Try something like 7-Zip, too. It typically achieves better compression rates than RAR and it's very definitely superior in that it is a free and unencumbered algorithm, while RAR archives can only be created by commercial software.

Comment: Highly depends on content of the file..I get a lot of mixed results depending on the content of the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible that the file is highly redundant with a repeating pattern that is larger than 32K.  gzip's deflate only looks 32K back for matches, whereas the others can capitalize on history much further back.

*Update:*

I just made a file that is a 64K block of random data, repeated 4096 times (256 MB).  gzip (with 32K window) was blind to the redundancy and so unable to compress it.  gzip expanded it to 256.04 MB.  xz (LZMA with 8 MB window) compressed it to 102 KB.

Comment: So, I can hopefully achieve this level of compression with LZMA module in python 3.3?

Comment: I would expect so.  You can try adjusting the preset parameter to more than 6 if it's not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

WinRAR and Gzip are two very different compression programs. They each use different algorithms to compress data. Here are the descriptions of each type from Wikipedia:

> Version 3 of RAR is based on Lempel-Ziv (LZSS) and prediction by partial matching (PPM) compression, specifically the PPMd implementation of PPMII by Dmitry Shkarin.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR#Compression_algorithm

And Gzip:

> It is based on the DEFLATE algorithm, which is a combination of Lempel-Ziv (LZ77) and Huffman coding.
>
> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip

My guess would be some sort of difference between how Prediction by partial matching and Huffman coding work. That file has very interesting properties though... What is the file?

Comment: I have added first 3 lines from my files, as you can see its mostly numbers and colons and semicolons.

Comment: @NilanjanBasu well, I just tried using 7zip, another archiver, and I got 215KB... And I stopped Gzip, because it was already at a couple of MBs after the first 30 seconds. Very unusual... 7zip uses a number of algorithms, LZMA, LZMA2, Bzip2, PPMd, and DEFLATE. Looks like prediction by partial matching may be key because WinRar and 7zip both have it...

Comment: On standard settings I got 171k with xz.  I think this file is kind of pathological in that each line looks a lot like a truncated/shifted version of the previous one.  I assume that's very good for PPM and very bad for anything else.